# #Batch | Set Programm ID to Variable and delete that

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

i hope someone can help me :-)

I need to remove OpenOffice, I found how I can get the ID and write it to a variable, which would then be deleted via mcshes. But I can not write the correct value in a variable.

Here is my code:

```
@echo on & setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*"  %%i IN ('wmic product where "name like 'OpenOffice%%'" get IdentifyingNumber /format:value') Do Set id=%%~i

    echo Die ID ist %id% 

    pause

    msiexec /uninstall !id!  /quiet /norestart

    echo OpenOffice Installation Errorlevel %Errorlevel%

    pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for /f` has two problems:

1. You can't enclose the command in `'` and also use them inside the command. (solution usebackq)
2. wmic output is crippled by an additional `CR` in the line ending `CRCRLF`
   (solution, process output with another for, or parse content eliminating the line end)

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\15\SO_50349950.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims={}" %%A in (
  `wmic product where "name like 'OpenOffice%%'" get IdentifyingNumber /format^:value 2^>NUL`
) Do Set "id={%%~A}"

echo Die ID ist %id% 
pause

msiexec /uninstall !id!  /quiet /norestart
echo OpenOffice Installation Errorlevel %Errorlevel%
pause
```

Sample output (searching the here present LibreOffice)

> Q:\Test\2018\05\15\SO_50349950.cmd
>   Die ID ist {DD7E9D37-CA78-459A-8BA8-29BBF29CF257}
>   Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .